# $mdDialog closing using a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I want to close [$mdDialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) after a successful promise return.

I can close $mdDialog like my following code but it doesn't fill my necessity on this purpose

```
vm.$mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'myController',
    templateUrl: 'myfile.html',
    clickOutsideToClose: true, 
    controllerAs: "vm",
    locals: {
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me providing any code snippet of a function with which i can close the Dialog
after a promise return or anywhere i want to close that

Comment: have you tried `$mdDialog.hide()` ?

Comment: used that it didn't return to the mother controller, from where the $mdDialog is called

Answer (score 2):

> *it didn't return to the mother controller, from where the `$mdDialog` is called*

The `$mdDialog.show()` method returns a promise that resolves with data or promise provided to the `$mdDialog.hide()` method:

```
var promise = vm.$mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'myController',
    templateUrl: 'myfile.html',
    clickOutsideToClose: true, 
    controllerAs: "vm",
    locals: {
    }
});

promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log("Cancelled", reason);
});
```

### Usage:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    $mdDialog.hide(response.data);
});
```